# Cell Value Change Event and Running a Continuous Macro

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I want my macro to run automatically when Sheet1 is open AND a value is changed in any of the drop down menus in Column B. I assume I can write a couple of event listener wrappers such as:

```
' pseudocode    
While Sheet1 is open
        When a dropdown value is changed in column B
            Call Update
        End When
End While
```

I've found a few links online, but I don't quite understand. In these links, they have code referring to Target. Is Target a named range? I haven't had any luck implementing these. I'm thinking these links could have an answer to my problem. 
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/95341-running-macro-continuously.html 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a worksheet event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rB As Range
    Set rB = Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If Intersect(Target, rB) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call Update
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: The code worked, thanks. Appreciate the extra links too.


`Set rB = Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)`
The above code makes my Target range all cells in B with validation? Interesting ... haven't seen this before. That makes one of my helper functions redundant.

Answer (score 1):

What you are going to need is a Worksheet_Changed event similar to this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Column("B")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call Update
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This will trigger if any changes are made in column B. The Target is supplied by the application event and is the range that had the change made.

Edit:
You will need to put this in the code of the sheet, not a module. If you right click on the sheet tab at the bottom of the excel screen, one of the options is view code.

Comment: It is imperative to turn off events if you are going to change data within the Change event! See @Gary'sStudent answer for example.