# Automatic Modification of Calculation

Tags: vba, excel

I created a code which allows me to sum (Consolidated) numbers from different cells in different sheets to a single sheet (Consolidation Sheet that holds the total - called sheet0)

I then created a button to activate these codes, and it works.

What I want know :
Is that each time I modify a number in any of my cells, it modifies directly my final result (on sheet0) without having to press another time on my button.

here is the code associated to my button :

```
Sub Consolidate()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'I thought this line would      help me 
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Consolidated As Long
For y = 2 To 152
For x = 2 To 14
    Consolidated = 0
    For Each Sheet In Sheets

        If Right(Sheet.Name, 5) = "E2016" Then

            If IsNumeric(Sheet.Cells(y, x).Value) Then
             Consolidated = Consolidated + CLng(Sheet.Cells(y, x).Value)
             Sheet0.Cells(y, x) = Consolidated
            End If

            If Not IsNumeric(Sheet.Cells(y, x).Value) Then
                Sheet0.Cells(y, x) = " "
            End If

            If IsEmpty(Sheet.Cells(y, x).Value) Then
                 Sheet0.Cells(y, x) = " "
            End If

       End If
   Next
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Idk why the site is cutting my Hello so I'll do it here ahah :
Helloooo guys! :)

Comment: you mean you want to auto start your function after changing values?

Comment: Yup exactly! Thats what Im trying but its not working :
    Function doubleMe(d)
        Application.Volatile
        doubleMe = d * 2
    End Function

Comment: never tried it... but i found something about events here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367344/cell-value-change-event-and-running-a-continuous-macro

Comment: Ok Im gonna throw an eye on it  to see if I can find something ! Thanks for your help anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in the comments you could use the `Change Event` to run your code each time that any of the sheets is changed. But that might slow down your Excel quite  bit because - after each change - your code will have to run.

So, I'd propose to rather use the event `Worksheet_Activate` on the condolidated sheet. So that your code will run each time that you are actually opening the Sheet0 to look at the consolidated numbers.

In order to achieve that go into the VBE and double-click on Sheet0 to see the code for that sheet. Then insert the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Call Consolidate

End Sub
```

Based on your comment it seems that you question / goal has changed. In order to get this dynamic formula on the Sheet0 you might want to try the following code (wihtout warranty as I couldn't test it without the actual sheet):

```
If IsNumeric(Sheet.Cells(y, x).Value2) Then
    If Len(Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula) = 0 Then
        Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula = "=SUM('" & Sheet.Name & "'!" & Sheet.Cells(y, x).Address & ")"
    Else
        Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula = Left(Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula, Len(Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula) - 1) & ",'" & Sheet.Name & "'!" & Sheet.Cells(y, x).Address & ")"
    End If
End If
```

Since I do not have your sheet, I wasn't able to test it. Hopefully it works as is. If not, at least you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help it works! But actually my boss wants it to be automatic without the activate action. For example when I click on my cells now, it only gives me the value, while now he wants the formula to appear in the cell. Im trying to work on it right now hehe
Still thanks a lot for your help, if I dont find a way to insert the formulas I'll keep it this way! :)

Comment: Great Ralph ! Thank you a lot man it almost works ! There is just a small bug but Im gonnna try to find out alone. Thanks again, I grandly appreciate your help !!

Comment: Sorry for being so annoying but if you could throw an eye on my last comment (in answers) it would be great :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you could just use a 3:dimensional reference inside SUM, something like:

=SUM(Sheet2:Sheet8!A1) or =SUM(Sheet2:Sheet8!A1:Z99)

Comment: Hello Charles! Thanks for your answer, but it must stay within VBA :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel really dumb, but I have a problem : it is that my formula (Credits to Ralph, upper) is working for all my cells instead the first one B:2. In this one there is no value, its the formula which is displayed in this form :
 ,'UAE E2016'!$B$2,'KSA E2016'!$B$2,'CYPRUS E2016'!$B$2,'QATAR E2016'!$B$2)

In other cells here is the formula : 
=SUM('LEB E2016'!$B$4,'UAE E2016'!$B$4,'KSA E2016'!$B$4,'CYPRUS E2016'!$B$4,'QATAR E2016'!$B$4) but the value is displayed if I dont click on the cell.
This one is what I need, and its working everywhere, but not in my first cell.

Its driving me crazy. Im trying to solve it with the break point but nothing to do I dont understand. Sorry for all these questions but I started VBA on my own 2 weeks and I really don't master it yet! here is the formula :

```
 Sub Consolidate()

 Dim Sheet As Worksheet
'Dim Consolidated As String
 For y = 2 To 152
 For x = 2 To 14
 'Consolidated = ""
    For Each Sheet In Sheets

        If Right(Sheet.Name, 5) = "E2016" Then

            If IsNumeric(Sheet.Cells(y, x).Value) Then
             'Consolidated = Consolidated + "+" + Sheet.Cells(y, x).Formula
             'Sheet0.Cells(y, x) = Consolidated
                    If Len(Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula) = 0 Then
                    Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula = "=SUM('" & Sheet.Name & "'!" & Sheet.Cells(y, x).Address & ")"
                   Else
                    Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula = Left(Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula, Len(Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula) - 1) & ",'" & Sheet.Name & "'!" &    Sheet.Cells(y, x).Address & ")"
                    End If
            End If


            If Not IsNumeric(Sheet.Cells(y, x).Value) Then
                Sheet0.Cells(y, x) = " "
            End If

            If IsEmpty(Sheet.Cells(y, x).Value) Then
                Sheet0.Cells(y, x) = " "
            End If

        End If
    Next
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that the first cell is not considered empty. Maybe there is merely a SPACE in that cell (not visible) or something else? Try it with this maybe: `If Left(Trim(Sheet0.Cells(y, x).Formula), 5) <> "=SUM(" Then`.

Comment: Give me your skills... haha

Comment: Now its working, but its missing my first sheet 'LEB
But I have the values which is displayed and my formula is better :
=SUM('UAE E2016'!$B$2,'KSA E2016'!$B$2,'CYPRUS E2016'!$B$2,'QATAR E2016'!$B$2)

Comment: Its ok I found my error, it was in my excel. Thanks for your help again Ralph! Good evening :)